# IndexOutOfBoundsException even though the elements exist in the arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

I have 10001 elements in the ArrayList when I am trying to remove them one by one, I get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception midway i.e. after 5000 elements. Don't really know why.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> numberArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> numberLinkedList = new LinkedList<>();

    long start, end;

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10_001; i++) {
      numberArrayList.add(i);
    }
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Time taken to insert 10_001 elements in ArrayList: " + (end - start));

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10_001; i++) {
      numberLinkedList.add(i);
    }
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Time taken to insert 10_001 elements in LinkedList: " + (end - start));

    /* **************************************************************/
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10_001; i++) {
      numberArrayList.remove(i);
    }
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Time taken to remove 10_001 elements from the front in ArrayList: " + (end - start));

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10_001; i++) {
      numberLinkedList.remove(i);
    }
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Time taken to remove 10_001 elements from the front in LinkedList: " + (end - start));


  }
```

The above program results in

```
Time taken to insert 100_001 elements in ArrayList: 2
Time taken to insert 100_001 elements in LinkedList: 1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5001, Size: 5000
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:496)
    at collections_jnit.list.ArrayList_vs_LinkedList.main(ArrayList_vs_LinkedList.java:34)
```

Comment: Because you are removing elements as you iterate it. Halfway through you have removed half of the elements and bam, now out of bounds.

Comment: `remove()` shifts the subsequent remaining elements down one index. So, after you've removed 5000 elements, the last index is 5000.

Comment: If you need remove all items ,just use `clear()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you remove 5000 elements mean 10001-5000 = 5001 so considering the indexing from `0` so now range of index is `0` to `5000` hence the exception with 5001.

Solution : if you want to remove items from list while traversing then I recommend to use `Iterators`

```
Iterator<Integer> itr = numberArrayList.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    itr.remove();
}
```

Comment: Why we need to iterate each item if we will clear all List ? I think `List.clear()` is safety.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine in this case, OP is doing some bench marking tests(so I didn't suggest ), although `clear` almost does the same thing using loops though it is concise and time effective

Comment: I have not a deep experience ,but i thought we use Iterator and removeIf () ..etc ,if we need to remove some items , i mean when we have a condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it to a while loop:

```
while (numberLinkedList.size() > 0) {
    numberLinkedList.remove(0);
}
```

With the for loop, you are removing the object at `i` which is increasing every iteration and thus you end up only removing half the items.

Answer (score 1):

As already answered, why you are getting `IndexOutOfBoundException`, so I am going to add, how can you safely remove all the elements. There are two ways of doing this:

1. [ArrayList.clear()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear())
2. [ArrayList.removeAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection))

Both of the methods are inherited from `List` into `ArrayList`. 1 is faster than 2.

Answer (score 0):

Lists are not Arrays.
If you add an element to a List with size `N` the list size will be increased, that means you can access the element `N + 1`. If you remove any element, you cannot access the element `N + 1`, this element will be in the position `N`.

Arrays has fixed positions and fixed size.

Please, look the documentation:

- [Array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)
- [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html)
- [Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html)
- [Sets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html)

Answer (score 0):

numberLinkedList.clear();

or if you want to iterate, Use Java 8+ :)

numberLinkedList.removeIf(i -> true);